# Using Python dict/set to memoize algebraic expressions

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I'm interested in storing expressions in self-referential classes, and these expressions may be duplicated. I'm looking for a recommendation for an approach. I have a couple in mind.

Example:

```
a + b
```

Now since addition is commutative, it would be nice if we recognize that `b + a` is the same expression. For the purposes of my application, recognizing and collapsing these cases is OK.

I've been cooking my noodle on this and come up with a couple ways of handling it:

1) Use a `set()` and define `__hash__` and `__eq__` for all the objects and this will allow me to uniquely define the expressions. One advantage is I can be clever and use xor of the operands to make it simpler to detect the commutative cases:

```
class Expr(object):
    def __init__(self, op, left, right):
        self.op = op
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(op) ^ hash(left) ^ hash(right)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.op == other.op and \
            ((self.left == other.left and self.right == other.right) \
            or (self.left == other.right and self.right == other.left))
```

One downside to this is that in order to test whether a given expression is already present, I will need to build up an object to test for membership. And if already in the set I would just be discarding it.

And I believe that as written this `__eq__` function will induce a full tree traversal when you compare two trees, which you don't want. Ideally the purpose of memoizing the trees is that a simple left/right pointer value comparison should uniquely identify a node.

2) Use a `dict()` and use a tuple of arguments you'd pass to the constructor. In order to handle commutative operations I can install keys for both `('+', 'a', 'b')` and `('+', 'b', 'a')` and assign it to the same object.

```
key = ('+', left, right)
if key in mydict:
    expr = mydict[key]
else:
    expr = Expr('+', left, right)
    mydict[key] = expr
    mydict[('+', right, left)] = expr

return expr
```

I can't use the xor method here because that doesn't produce a key that is guaranteed to be unique.

Here's where things get a little *more* interesting:

If you use the set()/xor method, you can detect associative equality. So, `(a + b) + c` and `a + (b + c)` *could* be treated as the same expression if you chose.

Comment: What is your question really? In any case it is important to know whether `Expr`s are immutable or not... if they are immutable you can cache the result of `__hash__` and even `__eq__`. Also: you could implement `__new__` and make it so that creating the instance `Expr('+', 'a', 'b')` returns the same instance as the existing one for `Expr('+', 'b', 'a')`. Having these "singletons" would allow identity comparison to check equality... is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You can have a normalize function, so that every identical expression ends up the same. For example, alphabetically sort things where the order does not matter. This adds some computation, whereas storing all the representations (e.g. +ab and +ba) adds some memory.

Comment: Don't store the arguments individually; store them as a tuple `(left, right)` for noncommutative operators and a frozen set `frozenset([a, b])` for commutative operators.

Comment: Yes @Bakuriu the expressions should be immutable. The question is more or less whether 1 or 2 is better. Or if other, then that's also worth considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve your solution `1` by caching the instances of `Expr` in such a way that order of the arguments is not important:

```
class CommutativeExpr(object):

    _instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, operator, left, right):
        key = (operator, frozenset([left, right]))
        try:
            return cls._instances[key]
        except KeyError:
            instance = cls._instances[key] = super().__new__(cls)
            return instance

    def __init__(self, operator, left, right):
        self.op = operator
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self._hash = hash((operator, frozenset([left, right])))

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self is other
```

This allows you to use identity check to verify that:

```
>>> CommutativeExpr('+', 'a', 'b') == CommutativeExpr('+', 'b', 'a')
True
```

This does not support "associativity", however you could add that functionality too by properly defining the `__hash__` and having `__eq__` do a more complex comparison.

---

Obviously non-commutative expressions will require a different implementation, which would be a different class or you'll have to increase the complexity of this class to fit both needs.

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, does your example really need to define a `__hash__` function? Since the class is not being used directly as a key and you're using a tailored tuple, it seems like it wouldn't be required?

Comment: @ClintOlsen `left` and `right` may be instances of `CommutativeExpr` and the tuple/frozenset hash is computed from the elements, so yes it is needed if you want to allow nested expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm marking your answer as solving this because it gave me enough leads. Thanks about the clue about `__new__`. That method of doing object *interning* will lead to a cleaner approach.

I still haven't fully thought out if I can extend this to handle associativity, but I don't think it's as critical as commutativity.

Comment: One issue I have found after incorporating this method of overriding `__new__` is that instances already present in the dictionary are *always* initialized (in `__init__()` of course) so I am re-computing `self._hash` unnecessarily.

Comment: @ClintOlsen you can check inside `__init__` whether the attributes are already set. For example `self._hash = self._hash if hasattr(self, "_hash") else hash((operator, frozenset([left,right])))`

Comment: Yes, this seems like a viable workaround, or I can push the interning check into the `__call__` method and use metaclasses it seems...